# Cómo hacer para integrar el rol , email y token

Tags: java, spring-security

Mi objetivo con este post es averiguar como hacer para obtener el email, rol de mi usuario que se inicia , primero deberia de fijarse en el backend.Estoy utilizando spring security.
Les paso el codigo importante:
JWT SERVICE:

```
@Service
    public class JwtService {

        @Value("${application.security.jwt.secret-key}")
        private String secretKey;
        @Value("${application.security.jwt.expiration}")
        private long jwtExpiration;
        @Value("${application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration}")
        private long refreshExpiration;

        public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
     
            final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
            return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
   
        }

        public String extractUsername(String token){
            return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
          
        }

        private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
           
            return Jwts 
                    .parserBuilder() 
                    .setSigningKey(getSignInKey()) 
                    .build() 
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody(); 


        }

        private Key getSignInKey() {
          
            byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey); 
            return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
 
        }

        public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {

            return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
        }

        public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims,UserDetails userDetails) {
            return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails, jwtExpiration);
        }

        public String generateRefreshToken(UserDetails userDetails){
            return buildToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails, refreshExpiration);
        }
//ACA ES DONDE  ESTOY INTENTANDO HACERLO PERO NO SE SI ESTA BIEN 
        private String buildToken(Map<String,Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails, long expiration){ //se utiliza para construir y generar un nuevo token JWT con información adicional y ciertos detalles de usuario

            List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities()
                    .stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
            claims.put("rol", ((User) userDetails).getRol());
            claims.put("email",((User) userDetails).getEmail());


            return Jwts
                    .builder() 
                    .setClaims(claims)
                    .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiration))
                    .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                    .compact();
        }

        public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
            final String username = extractUsername(token);
            return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
        }

        private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
            return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
        }

        private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
            return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
        }


    }
```

Mi idea es intentar obtener el email y rol del usuario para mi frontend.Gracias de antemano.
Si necesitan alguna parte mas del codigo avisenme y con gusto se los paso.

Comment: Por favor, no saltes el sistema automatico haciendo spam en la publicación. En su lugar, mejora la pregunta. En este caso, existe la posibilidad de que haya mucho código de más y la comunidad caresca de interés en revisarlo. Lectura recomendada [EMCV](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Lo logre : {
  "rol": "ADMIN",
  "sub": "admin@gmail.com",
  "iat": 1707602888,
  "exp": 1707689288
} mi pregunta es como hago para  obtenerlo en mi servicio de angular .Que debeira de user sessionStorage ? para obtener el rol , email del usuario